# MVC Input files sent as email attachments but content cleared and file size always 64b

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, email-attachments

So far I have a form which gets filled and has 3 possible files which can be uploaded and both saved as a database entry and sent as an email with the files as attachments.

I hadn't noticed it straight away but I think I missed something as although the files get the right type and name they all have no content and a file size of 64b.

Create page relevant content

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "RequestForm", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ctFRM", enctype = "multipart/form-data", @role = "form" }))
{  
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
           <label>Attachments</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-11" style="border: 1px solid #dedede; border-radius: 5px; padding: 5px; margin: 0 15px; ">
           <input type="file" name="AttachmentId1" /><br />
           <input type="file" name="AttachmentId2" /><br />
           <input type="file" name="AttachmentId3" />
      </div>
</div>
```

Controller action relevant content

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SDRequestVM sdvm, FormCollection fc)
{
     SDRequest sdr = sdvm.sdr;
     MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();


#region Attachment Code

            if (Request != null)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase crfile = Request.Files["AttachmentId1"];

                if ((crfile != null) && (crfile.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(crfile.FileName))
                {
                    string fileName = crfile.FileName;
                    string fileContentType = crfile.ContentType;
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[crfile.ContentLength];
                    crfile.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(crfile.ContentLength));
                    FileLibrary fl = new FileLibrary();
                    fl.FileName = fileName;
                    fl.FileType = fileContentType;
                    fl.FileContent = fileBytes;
                    fl.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    fl.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.User.Value;
                    db.FileLibraries.Add(fl);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    sdr.AttachmentId1 = fl.Id;
                    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(crfile.InputStream, crfile.FileName));
                }
                HttpPostedFileBase od1 = Request.Files["AttachmentId2"];

                if ((od1 != null) && (od1.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(od1.FileName))
                {
                    string fileName = od1.FileName;
                    string fileContentType = od1.ContentType;
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[od1.ContentLength];
                    od1.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(od1.ContentLength));
                    FileLibrary fl = new FileLibrary();
                    fl.FileName = fileName;
                    fl.FileType = fileContentType;
                    fl.FileContent = fileBytes;
                    fl.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    fl.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.User.Value;
                    db.FileLibraries.Add(fl);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    sdr.AttachmentId2 = fl.Id;
                    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(od1.InputStream, od1.FileName));
                }
                HttpPostedFileBase od2 = Request.Files["AttachmentId3"];

                if ((od2 != null) && (od2.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(od2.FileName))
                {
                    string fileName = od2.FileName;
                    string fileContentType = od2.ContentType;
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[od2.ContentLength];
                    od2.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(od2.ContentLength));
                    FileLibrary fl = new FileLibrary();
                    fl.FileName = fileName;
                    fl.FileType = fileContentType;
                    fl.FileContent = fileBytes;
                    fl.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    fl.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity.User.Value;
                    db.FileLibraries.Add(fl);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    sdr.AttachmentId3 = fl.Id;
                    msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(od2.InputStream, od2.FileName));
                }
            }

            #endregion Attachment Code
```

Save/Email send controller code

```
db.SDRequests.Add(sdr);
db.SaveChanges();
SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient();
c.Send(msg);
return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
```

Webconfig mail settings

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="ExampleAddress@example.example3.uk">
        <network host="smtp.example2.example3.uk" port="25" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

As far as I can see stepping through the code it should work unless I've made a mistake with the file.InputStream which gets added as a new attachment to the msg.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Can you please try this line in web.config?*

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240"  />
</system.web>
```

Comment: No difference, it's still sending 64b attachments with no content.

Comment: Ah I see you thought I had large files I was uploading, the files are a 10b .txt file and a 121kb .doc file so at least the .txt file shouldn't have been affected as it's orginal size was less than the replaced size.